# Problem with ListView highlight element and OnClickListener

Tags: android

I have a ListView with a RadioButton in it and a LinearLayout.
I want to manage the onClickListener on the LinearLayout, but I noticed 2 things:

1 - when I click on the LinearLayout it will not be highlighter; how to make it highlighted (orange) on the click or touch of the user?
2 - in the LinearLayout there are 2 TextView controls and the onClickListener works only when I click on them, it doesn't work when I click out of them. How to make the onClickListener work on the entire row?

Thank you very much in advance, bye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but are you looking for the [onItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)?
Assigning an onItemClickListener to your ListView causes a callback function to be called when an item of the ListView is clicked.

Might I ask why are you putting a radio button and a LinearLayout inside a ListView?